# Android expansion (obb) patch file version number

Tags: android, zip, patch, expansion, apk-expansion-files

I have uploaded my application to the Play Store with a huge expansion (obb) file. Everything's working fine, no problem with that. But now I have to upload a small update to the expansion file. I want to use the patch expansion file because I don't want to force the users to download the big main expansion file again. In theory it's seems to an easy task.

From the developer page:

```
// Get a ZipResourceFile representing a merger of both the main and patch files
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(appContext,
    mainVersion, patchVersion);`
```

I have used that in this form:

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile =
APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(appContext,
    14, 0);'
```

with no patch file and with no problem.

But if I try to modify this code, I got problems.

My current version is **19**, but I still use the main expansion file from the **14** version. When I tested my app I used 14 as the version number of my patch file (patch.14.com.exaple), copied the patch file directly to my phone and used this code:

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile =
APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(appContext,
    14, 14);
```

Everything's was fine, the app find the updated files in the ZipResourceFile so it's true, that the *"ZipResourceFile representing a merger of both the main and patch files"*...

I've tried upload the modified apk and the patch file in the developer console but after the upload I realised that it changed the patch file's name to the current version number: patch.19.com.exaple and I can't change it back to 14. So I cancel the upload and modified the code:

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile =
APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(appContext,
    14, 19);
```

But after that the app didn't find the updated files - it seems that it's only using the main file. I've tried to test it on my phone, changing the file names of the obb files and the code in the app, and I found, that this "merging" is working only if the version numbers are the same. But in this case the whole "main and patch obb files" is completly useless (at least in the context of APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile) *because I can't upload a patch file later with a version number of an earlier release...*

So my question is:
**how can I get a ZipResourceFile that "representing a merger of both the main and patch files" if the version numbers are different in the two filenames?**

Comment: did you figure it out? I have an app with version 0.0.9, is my version number just 9 then?